# Quarkus Apache CXF gives the error "No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown"

Tags: cxf, quarkus

Using wsdl2java I created the Java pojos to host a SOAP service in a Quarkus microservice.  When I hit the ?wsdl endpoint in a browser or via curl to show the wsdl of the SOAP service we are getting the following error:

"No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown"

which apparently means somehow the request is not matching the WSDL.  The generated interface has the following annotations:

@WebService(targetNamespace = http://myGeneratedNameSpace.com, name = "myGeneratedServiceName")

And the service implementation has the following annotation:

@WebService(serviceName = "myServiceName")

I attempted this in both Quarkus 3.0 as well as Quarkus 2.16.4, and both are giving the same error.  Is an annotation missing? Is there any way to add more logging to debug this further?  The error message is too generic.

UPDATE: See comment below. I was able to get a SOAP service working with the ?wsdl endpoint, but when I add the quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest extension it then shows the above error.  Is this expected behaviour?  Should I file a defect on this one? Intention here is to host REST/JSON microservices, but some clients cannot convert immediately so we also want to host a SOAP proxy service in front of the REST/JSON services. We will probably switch over to AWS Fargate but we wanted to use Lambda applications in lower environments.

Comment: I should add here: in Quarkus 3.0 I used the embedded wsdl2java in the Apache CXF extension, whereas in Quarkus 2.16 I used the wsdl2java in a separate project using Apache CXF 3.5.5 and then imported the java pojos

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproducer?

Comment: Ok, found something interesting.  Upgraded to Quarkus 3.0.3.Final, and implemented a simple dummy SOAP service. Service is the same except I added an endpointInterface in the @WebService, and the ?wsdl endpoint worked perfectly.  Then I added other Quarkus extensions with no extra code, and it then returned the same error as above.  I started commenting out the other Quarkus extensions, and isolated the culprit: including the extension quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest causes this.  Anyone know why? This happens in the local dev environment with no Lambda deployment

Comment: Got the same behavior with quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest @Nebulous